# How to split a string in equal halves

Tags: javascript, string, split

I'm trying to simulate a simple evolution thing using binary code. Each individual in the "gene pool" has their own unique string in binary code.

In order to have them mate, I need to take half of one string, and the other half of another and merge them. The problem is, I don't know how to split a string in two equal halves, and they are totally random.

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: find the length of the string. Then calc the middle `num = length/2`. Then find the substring from 0 to num and from num to len(str).

Comment: [Substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) could help you.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware that that is how sub-strings work.

Comment: Can the length be an odd number? That is the only special case.

Comment: How would you guarantee equal halves though, say the length was even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I would get the total length of the string and get the first half by doing

```js
myString.slice(firstIndex, secondIndex)
```

I would make the `firstIndex` be `0` and the `secondIndex` equal to `myString.length / 2`. That will return the first half of the string.

The second half of the string would be

```js
myString.slice(myString.length / 2, myString.length)
```

So, all together:

```js
const partOne = myString.slice(0, myString.length / 2)
const partTwo = myString.slice(myString.length / 2, myString.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string half1 = value.Substring(0, value.length/2);
string half2 = value.Substring(value.length/2);
```